# CSS Selector for First instance of class within block

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to target the first instance of a class within a block.

```css
.ContactPage-details div > .ContactPage-title ~ .ContactPage-title:not(:first-child) {
 background: none;
}

.ContactPage-details div > .ContactPage-title {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="ContactPage-details">
  <div class="ContactPage-telephone">
    <h3 class="ContactPage-title">The First paragraph.</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="ContactPage-emailAddress">
    <h3 class="ContactPage-title">The Second paragraph.</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="ContactPage-address">
    <h3 class="ContactPage-title">The Third paragraph.</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to target `<h3 class="ContactPage-title">The First paragraph.</h3>`

The first h3 parent can change, it may not always necessarily be `.ContactPage-telephone` so I cannot target it directly as it will differ depending on whether they have a telephone number listed in the database.

This is my current css to attempt to target the first instance of `ContactPage-title`

At the moment, all `h3`'s have a background of red and color of white.

Is there a way I can target the first instance of `ContactPage-title` without using javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your description of your problem:

No. CSS has `:first-child` and `:first-of-type` but not `:first-of-class`.

However, your example code makes it look like you actually want to target the `.ContactPage-title` that is a child of the first child in the block.

That would be:

```
.ContactPage-details > :first-child > .ContactPage-title {}
```